# Plotting shortest path in networks, with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am new to latex and wanted to draw the following network in Tikz:

[image]

```
The network is generated in R:

n = 100
p = 1.5/n
g = erdos.renyi.game(n, p)



# diameter
d = get.diameter(g)


E(g)$color = "grey"
E(g)$width = 1
E(g, path=d)$color = "red"
E(g, path=d)$width = 2
V(g)$color  = "SkyBlue2"
V(g)[d]$color = "red"
coords = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
plot(g, layout=coords, vertex.label = NA, vertex.size=3)
```

I thank you for any help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you do so far? Do you have any code that we could maybe develop? Is there any underlying algorithm or logic that plots the dots? And the connecting lines? Please post a minimal working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have you taken a look into the documentation of Ti*k*Z? You should do so and try to accomplish something on your own. If you encounter problems in the process, you can ask a specific question about that problem here. This page is not a do-it-for-me-service.

Comment: what you try so far? the simplest way is include this image in your document by `\includegraphics[...]{<image file name>}`. drawing it from scratch in `tikz` as well in `pstrick` is time demanding task in positioning and naming all of vertices.  after then, you can simple draw lines between them. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Something like finding the shortest path is probably not the best job for Ti*k*Z. Better calculate that using external software and then draw the path that software finds in Ti*k*Z. It will be agonisingly slow to do the whole thing in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Sorry for my naive question, I added the R code.

Comment: Sorry but if you plotted the graph in R, why don't you draw also the path with it and include the image in your LaTeX document with `\includegraphics[...]{<image file name>}` as Zarko said?

Comment: I have 20 more pics that cannot handle them in Latex, due to the high volume. I am trying to draw or convert pics in latex via Tikz, but I didn't know how to do it in R.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot handle in LaTeX due to high volume"? Also, I don't know how good the resulting code is, but have you looked at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html ?

Comment: I'm still a bit curious as to what exactly you meant in your last comment, could you clarify?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. I am sorry for confusing you. I converted the plots in R 2 latex format and don't have problem with big size photos.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by the OP as said in comment.